Lower the strength of left-shift implementation
I'm creating a toy scripting language in which integers are signed, 64bits. The language has support for bit twiddling, including shifting.
I want to have well defined semantics for shifting one int by another. That is: a << b and a >> b are always valid. For the left-shift, the shift count 'b' is clamped to [0, 64], with 64 resulting in integer value 0 (64 ints shifted in).
This the current OpCode handler for a left-shift.
My question is, can anyone think of a way to lower the strength of this code, to make it less expensive to perform. If the clamp and the ternary could be folder into 1 expression, that would be ideal.
The implementation language is C++
            // Script example code: l << r
            case BitShiftL: {
                i64 r = Pop(); 
                i64 l = Pop();
                u64 x = std::bit_cast<u64>(l);          // In C++, left-shifting signed negative ints is undefined, so interpret number as unsigned.
                i64 y = std::clamp(r, i64(0), i64(64)); // Keep 'r' in range [0, 64]
                u64 z = y == 64 ? u64(0) : x << y;      // If value is 64, result is 0; else perform shift.
                i64 v = std::bit_cast<i64>(z);          // Cast result back to signed int
                mStack.push_back(v); 
            } break;


I am presuming the shown snippet is the development language.  Please include it in the tags.  You might also provide documentation on your code so folks can more easily follow your thought process.

So you're saying you want to optimize code generation for a hypothetical language for arbitrary programs. Isn't that pre-premature optimization?

Of course instead of clamping and then doing a ternary you can write out the combined effect.

@PasserBy: The language is not hypothetical; it is reified. Making the interpreter of a language faster is not premature optimization, it's just normal programming.

It's not normal programming, that's what every premature optimization is justified by. Clearly you have a lot of code running per operation, and whatever you're doing here must take up a significant amount of time for this to be a sensible optimization.

If you don't mind changing the semantics, reducing the shift count modulo 64 (not "signed remainder", true modulo) would be cheaper to implement: x << (y & 63).

@harold: That's pretty decent, actually. Only issue being that shifting by 64 doesn't zero out the result anymore. But, like you said, would be a semantics change. Will consider it.

Actually, I take that comment back about x << (y & 63). It changes the semantics completely. Essentially, any number given above 63 would have completely unintuitive semantics. ei: decimal 64 (0b1000000), would have shift-value of 0. Still appreciate the suggestion, though.

Yes, it's quite different. Although I don't think it's necessarily bad, and there is plenty of precedent for it (eg Java, C#, x64 assembly in the most important cases). Looking purely at those semantics themselves, they work out well in some contexts (such as implementing a rotate) and poorly in others (such as generating a mask with k set bits, (1 << k) - 1 has an ugly edge case this way)

Clamp to a valid range.  i64 y = std::clamp(r, i64(0), i64(63));  Handle 64 as a special case to 0 out the value.  Handle anything else as an error (however your scripting language handles errors).  Profile the optimized code to see how the scripting engine performs.

As a variant, you may consider special-casing only the "count >= 64" case (saving half the logic) and destroying negative counts with y & 63 eg y >= 64 ? 0 : x << (y & 63). Then you still save some cost, you preserve the over-shift behaviour, and negative shift counts only really come up when optimizing 64 - k to -k or whatever (which would still work so even that's preserved), at the cost of being .. weird semantics

What assembly language are you using that doesn't have shift or rotate instructions?

I don't understand.  How can a shift operation have a strength?  Your assembly language should have instructions for: left shift, rotate left (using carry bit), right shift, and rotate right.  Usually the difference between rotate and shift is that rotate involves the carry bit.

@ThomasMatthews: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction

I decided to just byte the bullet and accept the C++ shifting semantics. I'll clamp to range [0,63] and then just do l << r.  I'm choosing to remove the comparison and conditional, and abandoning defining over-shifting to mean 0. In other words, I'm optimizing for the common case.

@PasserBy No, it isn’t premature optimization, it is interpreter design. Every cycle is valuable. This is what compiler writers do all day long.

@user207421 You're telling me compiler writers randomly picks a thing to optimize, without first understanding whether it's impactful, without benchmarks to demonstrate whatever you're doing even works, and insists on the ephemeral "optimization" to the extent they'd rather change the semantics of the language? I have an exceedingly hard time believing that.

@PasserBy is right. To take an example, every version of Python brings a huge performance increase over the prevous one. The old versions must have been very bad for it to be possible. Did it prevent Python from being a hugely successful language? Not in any measure. Also, this case goes against the first 3 points of the C++ core guideline / Performance. Unless you consider yourself a developer than Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter, just do what they say.
